# Объединить данные из двух файлов

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Не могу победить while и for.

Есть два файла:
./.hgsub

```
cmake = common/cmake
qt = common/qt
proj = project/code
js = project/code_js

[subpaths]
^(\w+:\/\/)(([^@:/]+(:[^@:/]+)?@)?[-a-zA-Z0-9_.]+(:[0-9]+)?\/scm\/hg)(\/[^/]+)*(\/[^/]+)\/([^/]+)$ = \1\2\7/\8
```

./.hgsubstate

```
89d184e1d854d0bb86d0998cad396bc2ddf81735 cmake
b80783d4ef42b23936ff3bb890a58333a61b4c67 qt
1f05c071fd7df1a6d4b58cbc9bc6f947fb2488b1 js
4a8f4ab29f5af9b829e16068706ce85782f15a62 proj
```

Идея следующая:

- читать каждую строчку файла *./.hgsub* до тех пор, пока нет пустой строки или [subpaths];
- разбить строчку в *./.hgsub* разделителем '=';
- взять переменную $1 (в первой строчке это cmake, например) и вывести строчку совпадающую по данной переменной из файла *./.hgsubstate*;
- разбиваем эту строку на $state1 и $state2 (не уверен в этой необходимости);
- соединяем $2 из файла *./.hgsub* и $state1 из *./.hgsubstate*

В итоге должна получиться строчка **common/cmake 89d184e1d85...d396bc2ddf81735** улетающая/добавляющаяся в файл.

Итог конечного файла:

```
common/cmake 89d184e1d854d0bb86d0998cad396bc2ddf81735
common/qt b80783d4ef42b23936ff3bb890a5a61b4c67
project/code 4a8f4ab29f5af9b829e16068706ce85782f15a62
project/code_js 1f05c071fd7df1a6d4b58cbc9bc6f947fb2488b1
```

**UPD:** насочинял пока такое. Нужно понять, как соединить ${VAR[0]} $1 и закинуть в цикл.

```
VAR=(`awk -F'=' '{print $1, $2}' ./.hgsub`) | grep ${VAR[0]} ./.hgsubstate | awk -F' ' '{print $1}'
```

Comment: Это делается *sed* в один присест, если я правильно понял задачу.

Comment: @0andriy да инструменты мне известны. Реализовать никак не могу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

с помощью программы, написанной на языке, понятном интерпретатору *bash*, конечно, можно реализовать требуемое, но это будет довольно громоздко.

лучше всё-таки использовать более подходящие для обработки текста программы.

например, для объединения полей из двух файлов (по совпадающим полям) можно использовать программу *join* (из пакета *gnu/coreuitls*, как и упомянутые далее программы).

1. вам надо объединить строки по значениям первого поля из первого файла и второго поля из второго файла. это указывается опциями `-1 1` и `-2 2`
2. вам надо вывести третье поле из первого файла и первое поле из второго. это указывается опцией `-o 1.3,2.1`

итого:

```
$ join -1 1 -2 2 -o 1.3,2.1 файл1 файл2
```

но имеющиеся файлы в первозданном виде не подходят: в первом пристутствуют лишние строки и оба не отсортированы по тем полям, по которым их будет объединять программа *join*.

1. вывести из первого файла строки до первой пустой можно, например, так: `sed -n '1,/^$/p' файл1`
2. отсортировать можно программой *sort*. если сортировать надо не по первому полю, то можно воспользоваться опцией `-k номер-поля`.
3. подставить вместо имён файлов результаты выполнения команд можно с помощью с помощью операторов [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html): `join ... <(команда1) <(команда2)`

итого:

```
$ join -1 1 -2 2 -o 1.3,2.1 <(sed -n '1,/^$/p' файл1 | sort) <(sort -k 2 файл2)
```

на ваших данных получилось:

```
common/cmake 89d184e1d854d0bb86d0998cad396bc2ddf81735
project/code_js 1f05c071fd7df1a6d4b58cbc9bc6f947fb2488b1
project/code 4a8f4ab29f5af9b829e16068706ce85782f15a62
common/qt b80783d4ef42b23936ff3bb890a58333a61b4c67
```

если надо отсортировать по первому полю, то добавьте ещё один вызов программы *sort*:

```
$ ... | sort
```

Comment: Идеально. Спасибо.

Comment: А не подскажите, почему при выполнении данной конструкции из скрипта, выпадает ошибка?  $ sh ./buildinfo.sh
./buildinfo.sh: 1: ./buildinfo.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: наверно, что-то неправильно написали. попробуйте без скрипта.

Comment: Без скрипта работает. Странно, работает если запускать bash ./buildinfo.sh , хотя в самом файле шебанг на bash есть, но и без sh не хотел. Вроде понял свой косяк с оболочкой

Comment: так bash и sh — это совершенно разные интерпретаторы. даже если под вторым именем запускается именно /bin/bash, он будет вести себя posix-совместимо. к примеру, process substitution не будет работать.

Comment: Cообразил. запускал на Jenkins, и не было шебанга в самой конфигурации и он запускал по умолчанию sh